# How to set rules for generic type parameters in VisualStudio?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, editorconfig

The picture below shows the warning I keep getting in Visual Studio 2017:

[image]

I got this off some website and I have tried all sorts of things. Does anyone know how I can get rid of this?

Here is my the part of my .editorconfig related to naming:

```
###############################
# Naming Conventions          #
###############################

# Style Definitions
dotnet_naming_style.pascal_case_style.capitalization               = pascal_case

dotnet_naming_style.camel_case_style.capitalization                = camel_case

dotnet_naming_style.I_prefix_style.required_prefix                 = I
dotnet_naming_style.I_prefix_style.capitalization                  = pascal_case

# Use PascalCase for constant fields
dotnet_naming_rule.constant_fields_should_be_pascal_case.severity  = warning
dotnet_naming_rule.constant_fields_should_be_pascal_case.symbols   = constant_fields
dotnet_naming_rule.constant_fields_should_be_pascal_case.style     = pascal_case_style
dotnet_naming_symbols.constant_fields.applicable_kinds             = field
dotnet_naming_symbols.constant_fields.applicable_accessibilities   = *
dotnet_naming_symbols.constant_fields.required_modifiers           = const

# Use PascalCase for public fields
dotnet_naming_rule.pascal_case_for_public_fields.severity          = warning
dotnet_naming_rule.pascal_case_for_public_fields.symbols           = public_fields
dotnet_naming_rule.pascal_case_for_public_fields.style             = pascal_case_style
dotnet_naming_symbols.public_fields.applicable_kinds               = field
dotnet_naming_symbols.public_fields.applicable_accessibilities     = public

# Interfaces must be PascalCase and have an I prefix
dotnet_naming_rule.interfaces_start_with_I.severity                = warning
dotnet_naming_rule.interfaces_start_with_I.symbols                 = any_interface
dotnet_naming_rule.interfaces_start_with_I.style                   = I_prefix_style
dotnet_naming_symbols.any_interface.applicable_accessibilities     = *
dotnet_naming_symbols.any_interface.applicable_kinds               = interface

# Classes, structs, methods, enums, events, properties, namespaces, delegates must be PascalCase
dotnet_naming_rule.general_naming.severity                         = warning
dotnet_naming_rule.general_naming.symbols                          = general
dotnet_naming_rule.general_naming.style                            = pascal_case_style
dotnet_naming_symbols.general.applicable_kinds                     = class,struct,enum,property,method,event,namespace,delegate
dotnet_naming_symbols.general.applicable_accessibilities           = *

# Everything else is camelCase
dotnet_naming_rule.everything_else_naming.severity                 = warning
dotnet_naming_rule.everything_else_naming.symbols                  = everything_else
dotnet_naming_rule.everything_else_naming.style                    = camel_case_style
dotnet_naming_symbols.everything_else.applicable_kinds             = *
dotnet_naming_symbols.everything_else.applicable_accessibilities   = *
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# prefix_type_parameters_with_t_style - Generic Type Parameters must be PascalCase and the first character must be a 'T'
dotnet_naming_style.prefix_type_parameters_with_t_style.capitalization = pascal_case
dotnet_naming_style.prefix_type_parameters_with_t_style.required_prefix = T
```

You can get nice set of rules [from here](https://github.com/RehanSaeed/EditorConfig).

Comment: Does this actually work for people, e.g. in Visual Studio Version 17.2.5? For me the text editor seems to ignore any `symbol_groups.applicable_kinds=type_parameter` I set in my EditorConfig file. Also the _Tools->Options->Text Editor->C#->Code Style->Naming_ dialog does not give 'Type Parameter' as an option in the Specification dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

add this in `.editorconfig`

```
# prefix_type_parameters_with_t_style - Generic Type Parameters must be PascalCase and the first character must be a 'T'
dotnet_naming_style.prefix_type_parameters_with_t_style.capitalization = pascal_case
dotnet_naming_style.prefix_type_parameters_with_t_style.required_prefix = T

dotnet_naming_symbols.type_parameter_group.applicable_kinds = type_parameter
dotnet_naming_rule.type_parameter_rule.symbols              = type_parameter_group
dotnet_naming_rule.type_parameter_rule.style                = prefix_type_parameters_with_t_style
dotnet_naming_rule.type_parameter_rule.severity             = warning
```